# jQuery accordion doesn't remove the class on click on the previous accordion

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, sass

I am making an FAQs section and I have some trouble with making the accordions act right.

When I click them one by one and close them before I open the next one, it's all fine. However if I open one, leave it open, and then click on the next one, the "show" class remains on the previous one.

I hope I am making myself clear, you can see what Im talking about in my code:

```js
$(".js-accordion").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var $this = $(this);

  if ($this.next().hasClass("show")) {
    $this.removeClass("show");
    $this.next().removeClass("show");
    $this.next().stop().slideUp(350);
  } else {
    $this.addClass("show");
    $this.parent().parent().find("div .accordion__inner").removeClass("show");
    $this.parent().parent().find("div .accordion__inner").stop().slideUp(350);
    $this.next().stop().toggleClass("show");
    $this.next().stop().slideToggle(350);
  }
});
```

```css
.accordion__box {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 14px 20px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.accordion__inner {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.accordion__header {
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #004a80;
  padding: 20px 30px 20px 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.accordion__header.show {
  background-color: #EF2A72;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.accordion__header.show::after {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.accordion__header::after {
  content: "\f107";
  color: #fff;
  max-width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion__box">
    <div class="accordion__header js-accordion">Who is this program for?</div>
    <div class="accordion__inner">
      <p>I’ve created this program for busy women of any age. No matter what your current weight… fitness level… or schedule looks like — this workout is for you. If you want to get a lifted, toned and curvy booty that’s also strong and athletic, this program
        is yours.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion__box">
    <div class="accordion__header js-accordion">Why is this method better than others?</div>
    <div class="accordion__inner">
      <p>I’ve created this program for busy women of any age. No matter what your current weight… fitness level… or schedule looks like — this workout is for you. If you want to get a lifted, toned and curvy booty that’s also strong and athletic, this program
        is yours.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/christmastrex/pen/oNzQEva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.not()` to exclude all elements which is not inside `accordion__box` where `js-accordion` is been clicked.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(".js-accordion").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var $this = $(this);
  $this.toggleClass("show")//add show to one which is clicked
  $this.closest(".accordion").find(".js-accordion").not($this).removeClass("show")//remove from other
  $this.next().slideToggle(350);//show accrodian
  $this.closest(".accordion").find(".accordion__inner").not($this.next()).stop().slideUp(350);//slideup another


});
```

```css
.accordion__box {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 14px 20px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.accordion__inner {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.accordion__header {
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #004a80;
  padding: 20px 30px 20px 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.accordion__header.show {
  background-color: #EF2A72;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.accordion__header.show::after {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.accordion__header::after {
  content: "\f107";
  color: #fff;
  max-width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion__box">
    <div class="accordion__header js-accordion">Who is this program for?</div>
    <div class="accordion__inner">
      <p>I’ve created this program for busy women of any age. No matter what your current weight… fitness level… or schedule looks like — this workout is for you. If you want to get a lifted, toned and curvy booty that’s also strong and athletic, this program
        is yours.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion__box">
    <div class="accordion__header js-accordion">Why is this method better than others?</div>
    <div class="accordion__inner">
      <p>I’ve created this program for busy women of any age. No matter what your current weight… fitness level… or schedule looks like — this workout is for you. If you want to get a lifted, toned and curvy booty that’s also strong and athletic, this program
        is yours.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much! Exactly was I was looking for